# Render scene using multiple GPUS

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

Are any script adjustments needed to render a scene using multiple GPUs or `bpy.data.scenes[0].cycles.device = 'GPU'` selects automatically all the available GPUs

Comment: You need to enable them in the preferences as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154512/74827

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Comment: This won't work for blender 2.8 check the solution I have written.

Comment: What didn't work for you? It should work in 2.80, I've written and tested both the snippet and add-on in that version.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but running it for the first time didn't work for me. Now I have second tested it and it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Consider upvoting answers on Blender's StackExchange that you find useful, it helps other people find good answers more easily.

Comment: I gave you upvote for your first comment :)

Comment: Thank you! I was just letting you know, in case you didn't already know about it before. Votes are anonymous, that's why I couldn't tell.