# GPU rendering via CLI not working in 2.81

Tags: python, gpu, command-line

Blender 2.81 seems to have broken CLI headless rendering with CUDA GPU.

Here's the Py script people often use: [Rendering on command-line with GPU?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156503/rendering-on-command-line-with-gpu)

- `blender -b *.blend -a -E CYCLES -P script.py`
- Blend file has CUDA enabled on another machine
- Shows line that says `Activating GTX 1080 Ti`
- `nvidia-smi` shows 0% usage, CPUs are 100%

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: The order of your CLI arguments appears to be wrong. The `-a` should be the last one, otherwise you're starting to render before setting the render engine and enabling the GPUs. Writing this from my phone, will have to verify later.

Comment: That solved it, strange but works!

Comment: Great, I will add it as an answer within the next days. It's not strange though, the importance of argument order is also documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender's command line interface executes the argument in the order they are given, as documented in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order). Therefore your command renders the animation (`-a`, `--render-anim`) *before* executing the Python script (`-P`, `--python`). Hence the GPU is enabled *after* the rendering is already done.

If you put the `-a` argument last, it should properly render the animation on the GPU.