# How do I do GPU rendering with enabled OptiX from the Command Line?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, command-line

I need help running Blender from the command line with GPU rendering. Also, Optix must be enabled.

I read this article:

> [How do I do GPU rendering from the Command Line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191204/how-do-i-do-gpu-rendering-from-the-command-line)

very much helped, but now I would like to know how to do the same with Optix

Comment: Can't you use `--cycles-device OPTIX`? **Source** - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
I didn't wait for an answer and started digging the internet, and yes I found exactly the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to everyone who helped!
I found a solution to the problem:

```
-b $filename -noaudio -E 'CYCLES' -s 20 -e 170 -a -F 'PNG' -- --cycles-device OPTIX
```

Explanation:

```
-s 20 -e 170
```

Set the `-s` start frame to 20 and the `-e` end frame to 170.

```
-a
```

Render the whole animation using all the settings saved in the blend-file.

```
-- --cycles-device OPTIX
```

Override the device that is used to render frames.