# Can blender use multiple GPUs in command line mode?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I just found that Blender can use multiple GPUs to speed up rendering when using the GUI mode.
However, can it also use multiple GPUs when rendering from command line mode?  Do I need to set any parameters for it to do that?  I'm using Blender 2.9.  Thanks!

Comment: You could use a Python script to enable the GPUs. [Does this answer your question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156503/rendering-on-command-line-with-gpu) Please note that the script only handles CUDA and OpenCL. For OptiX it would have to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Blender uses both GPUs when doing command line rendering without having to do anything.