# Compute Device Selection for a shared Blender Version

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, gpu, network

I am writing python scripts in blender for a team of 3D-Artists.
The scripts and the blender version are on a **network** drive "R:".
When calling the script

```
R:\blender-2.82a\blender.exe -b --python-expr "import bpy; print(bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.devices.keys());"
```

The output for **everybody** is:

```
['GeForce GTX 1050', 'AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics']
```

Which are **my** devices. The 3D-Artists have **other** devices.
Can it be that the devices listed in the cycles addon are not derived at runtime? Or how could that happen?
I want to activate the gpu for every 3D-Artist respectively, based on their **own** hardware.

Best,
Manuel

Comment: You haven't retrieved the current list of devices through `get_devices()`. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/how-to-select-all-non-cpu-cuda-or-non-cpu-opencl-devices-for-cycles-rendering-c) for reference. Note that the answer hasn't been updated to include OptiX.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Robert's answer was the key.
Apparently the array in bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.devices holds all devices that have ever been activated and saved in the blender gui. In order to get the current hardware and **to update the devices array**, you call:

```
preferences = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
cuda_devices, opencl_devices = preferences.get_devices()
```

And then you do something like:

```
gpu_device = None

for device in preferences.devices:
    device.use = False #reset all other devices
    if device.type == "CUDA" and device in cuda_devices:
        gpu_device = device

bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = "GPU"
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.compute_device_type = gpu_device.type
gpu_device.use = True

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.engine = "CYCLES"
    scene.cycles.device = "GPU"
```

Comment: Bless you. This works wonderfully for headless renders on 2.92.0.